# Select all categories who has items that are active in them?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I didn't knew what title should I put, feel free to edit of course, English not my native language.

I have linked LINQ2SQL database that has `Items` and `Categories` in it. `Items` table has field `IsActive`.

How can I select all categories that has items in them who has `IsActive` set to `true`? I can select all items very easily `var items = _db.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);` but can I somehow now select all categories that are associated with these items that I just selected?

My knowledge of LINQ is very limited so I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: you're looking for a [join](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like as below

For each items active

```
var items = _db.Cateogry.Where(x => x.Items.All( y=>y.IsActive == true));
```

for any item active

```
var items = _db.Cateogry.Where(x => x.Items.Any( y=>y.IsActive == true));
```

Comment: That would only give the categories where every one of the items were active.

Comment: This helped me, I tried with `All` and it didn't work, however `Any` worked good.

Comment: @Qmal - i though that you need to check all anyways i updated my answer with any also..

Comment: But why `Any` gave me back results when `All` gave empty result?

Comment: @Qmal - All means all the items of collection need to satisfy the condition ...Any means any item of the collection need to satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the appropriate association property is present, you can do:

```
var activeCategories = from category in _db.Categories
                       where category.Items.Any(item => item.IsActive)
                       select category;
```

If you must do a join, try something like:

```
var activeCategories = from category in _db.Categories
                       join item in _db.Items on category.Id equals item.CategoryId
                                                  into categoryGroup
                       where categoryGroup.Any(i => i.IsActive)
                       select category;
```

(or)

```
var activeCategories = from category in _db.Categories
                       join item in _db.Items.Where(i => i.IsActive)
                                 on category.Id equals item.CategoryId
                                 into categoryGroup
                       where categoryGroup.Any()
                       select category;
```

(or)

```
var activeCategories = from category in _db.Categories
                       where _db.Items
                                .Where(i => i.IsActive)
                                .Select(i => i.CategoryId)
                                .Contains(category.Id)
                       select category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each item has a CategoryID or similar, then:

```
from c in db.Categories
  where db.Items.Any(it => it.CategoryID == c.ID && it.IsActive)
  select c;
```

It's worth noting:

```
(from c in db.Categories join it in db.Items
  on c.ID equals it.CategoryID
  select c).Distinct();
```

Which is a bit needless in this case, but there are common variants upon this latter that gives you more than you can do with the former.